# Why doesn't Java assume the type after checking it?

Tags: java, types, casting

Why does Java not allow you do something like the commented out line?

```
public static void example(Object other) {
    if (!(other instanceOf Person)) {
        return;
    } else {
        Person p = (Person) other;
        System.out.println(p.name);
        // System.out.println(other.name);
    }   
}
```

I understand Java is statically typed, so types must be known at compile time and that is why you must explicitly cast `Object` to `Person`. But, is there a scenario where doing something similar to the commented out line would crash the program or be dangerous? It is logical that in order to enter the `else` clause, the type must be Person, so why doesn't Java know this?

What is an example of a similar scenario where this would not be safe?

Comment: There isn't necessarily a specific problem. It's just not how the language was designed. Some IDE's, like Eclipse, can automatically insert a cast by inferring the type in such a case.

Comment: @shmosel Gotcha, so not doing things like this is merely a result of trying to stick to the statically typed design of the language?

Comment: Strictly taken a variable can be repopulated (possibly with another type) meaning the code might give problems. But thats basically a shortcomming of the compiler IMO (since it does detect and allow 'effectivly final' variables for instance, which is basically the same principle for a compiler)

Comment: that is sort of coming to java-12 in switch statements only though

Comment: If the cast succeeds, then the call to `other.name` cannot fail. I think it's a design choice of the language; I would find such type juggling rather confusing.

Comment: It would have the benefit that you wouldn't need a second variable.  You could just write `(Person) other;` instead of `Person p = (Person) other;`.

Comment: If you allowed this, you would have a very hard time to draw the line between what’s allowed and what isn’t. How hard the compiler should try to infer the relevant types. And programmers would have a very hard time trying to understand those rules. Today there’s a simple rule, at compiletime a variable has its compiletime type. I much prefer it this way, it’s easy to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no logical reason why it couldn't. The language just wasn't designed this way. It's not a feature that you can add without breaking backwards compatibility, and Java has always made backwards compatibility a priority - it's one of the reasons that it's so successful.

Kotlin allows you to do this (they call it a [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts)) and Kotlin compiles to the same bytecode as Java. So there's no technical why Java couldn't do it, it just doesn't.

That said, we might get a feature like this eventually. It's [just a candidate at the moment](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305). The proposed syntax is something like:

```
if (x matches Integer i) {
    // can use i here
}
```

so it looks like `x` would stay the same, and a new variable `i` would be declared with given type.

Comment: now that I think about it, if java would have allowed `var` as method arguments, this would make a lot more sense, this is probably why kotlin allows it - since they can always infer the type from the code, but here it is a plain `Object`...

Answer (score 0):

In Java every class is a child of Object so you can pass/assign any class object to Object but the Object doesn't have any idea about the properties of your class. Here in your case Person class has name property and you assigned to it but Object doesn't about the name property of Person.

To answer your question of falling into else block would not mean the object you are passing should be Person Object it can be it child class as well and again if the child class of Person has some property that may not be known to Person class.

```
    public class TestPolymporphism {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Male m = new Male();
        Female f = new Female();
        test(m);
        test(f);
    }

    public static void test(Object obj){
        System.out.println(obj instanceof Person);
        System.out.println(obj instanceof Male);
    }
}

class Person {
    String name;
}

class Male extends Person {

}

class Female extends Person {

}
```